# Schedule repeating Org event for day of month

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to schedule something in Org for the 2nd Sunday of every month, or some criteria like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the answers provided here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555385/org-mode-how-to-schedule-repeating-tasks-for-the-first-saturday-of-every-month

This should work:

```
* Every 2nd Sunday! SCHEDULED: <%%(diary-float t 0 2)>
```